# Is it possible to get a recursive directory listing with details in Windows?

Tags: command-line, powershell, batch, cmd.exe, directory-listing

For example, suppose I want to see the file sizes of all the `*.txt` files in a tree. Currently, I can do:

```
dir *.txt /s
```

But the list is not formatted well and is hard to use.

I would like to know if the following example is possible using CMD (or if necessary, PowerShell):

```
C:\files>dir cache.sqlite /s

 Volume in drive C is HDD
 Volume Serial Number is 6789-ABCD

01/02/2005  00:01 AM            65,536  C:\files\about+addons\cache.sqlite
02/03/2006  01:04 AM            98,304  C:\files\app.asana.com\cache.sqlite
03/04/2007  02:07 AM         2,162,688  C:\files\app.slack.com\cache.sqlite
04/05/2008  03:10 AM            98,304  C:\files\bootstrap-vue.org\cache.sqlite
05/06/2009  04:13 AM           196,608  C:\files\dev.to\cache.sqlite
06/07/2010  05:16 AM            65,536  C:\files\developer.mozilla.org\cache.sqlite
07/08/2011  06:19 AM            98,304  C:\files\phys.org\cache.sqlite
08/09/2012  07:22 AM           786,432  C:\files\stackdev.io\cache.sqlite
09/10/2013  08:25 AM           458,752  C:\files\todo.zenkit.com\cache.sqlite
10/11/2014  09:28 AM            98,304  C:\files\www.bing.com\cache.sqlite
11/12/2015  10:31 AM            98,304  C:\files\www.infoworld.com\cache.sqlite
12/13/2016  11:34 AM            65,536  C:\files\www.oracle.com\cache.sqlite
01/14/2017  12:37 PM            98,304  C:\files\www.popularmechanics.com\cache.sqlite
02/15/2018  13:40 PM           327,680  C:\files\www.sitepoint.com\cache.sqlite
03/16/2019  14:43 PM            65,536  C:\files\www.yahoo.com\cache.sqlite
04/17/2020  15:46 PM            98,304  C:\files\www.zdnet.com\cache.sqlite
     Total Files Listed:
              24 File(s)     4,882,432 bytes
              16 Dir(s)  208,862,339,072 bytes free
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\files\*.txt" -Recurse | Select @{Name="MB Size";Expression={ "{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB) }}, Fullname, LastWriteTime;`

Comment: so you want the standard CMD.exe result of `dir c:\temp /A-d` ... but you want the full path instead of the filename + extension? ///// from what i can tell, you cannot do that with just CMD/BAT stuff. you can build it with PoSh. ///// do you need that EXACT layout? it's not a normal one, but a simple list of files that you show is EASY in PoSh. [*grin*]

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT Thanks, that's a great answer. Any particular reason you made it a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Also, do you know if there's a way to split `Fullname` down to remove the current directory?  I.e., running it in the folder `C:\temp\stuff` removes `C:\temp\stuff` from `Fullname` ?

Comment: @DrinkMorePimpJuiceIT, thank you! I should have been more clear in my "split" question. If we're in `c:\temp\stuff\ ` and a filename is `c:\temp\stuff\folder1\contents\file.txt`, I would like the current directory stripped from the file name, leaving the remaining directory parts, like this: `folder1\contents\file.txt`

Comment: The fact that this question generated so many convoluted answers with complicated scripts has been a fundamental flaw in MS-DOS and Windows for over 30 years.  The command shell "dir" command should have a "/r" option that gives exactly what the OP is requesting--and it should default to sorting by file date.  Such an easy miss by Microsoft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [get-childitem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html) and select the file property values with or without using [calculated properties](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/) to assist in getting the desired output values.

#### Recursive with file fullname and a calculated property "MB Size"

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\files\*.txt" -Recurse | 
Select @{Name="MB Size";Expression={ "{0:N1}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB) }}, Fullname, LastWriteTime;
```

**Output**

```
MB Size FullName                           LastWriteTime
------- --------                           -------------
21.2    C:\Files\Cell356.txt               2/24/2021 8:33:58 AM
0.9     C:\Files\Test123\best.txt          2/24/2021 8:16:29 AM
5.1     C:\Files\Test123\Test321\test.txt  2/24/2021 6:19:08 AM
0.5     C:\Files\Zeta\Cool123.txt          2/24/2021 6:13:05 AM
4.0     C:\Files\ZZettaa\zest.txt          2/24/2021 8:57:58 PM
```

#### Non-Recursive with file name and a calculated property "MB Size"

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\files\*.txt" | 
Select @{Name="MB Size";Expression={ "{0:N1}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB) }}, Name, LastWriteTime;
```

**Output Example**

```
MB Size Name         LastWriteTime
------- ----         -------------
21.2    Cell356.txt  2/24/2021 8:33:58 AM
0.9     best.txt     2/24/2021 8:16:29 AM
5.1     test.txt     2/24/2021 6:19:08 AM
0.5     Cool123.txt  2/24/2021 6:13:05 AM
4.0     zest.txt     2/24/2021 8:57:58 PM
```

### Recursive with parent folder removal

```
$sdir = "c:\temp\stuff\";
Get-ChildItem -Path $sdir -Filter "*.txt" -File -Recurse |
Select  @{Name = "MB Size"; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB) }}, 
        @{Name = "sDir"; Expression = { $_.FullName.Replace($sdir,"") }}, 
        Fullname, LastWriteTime
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ChildItem](https://ss64.com/ps/get-childitem.html)
- [Select-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/select-object.html)

  > Standard Aliases for Select-Object: `select`
- [Add a calculated property with Select-Object in PowerShell](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/)
- [Replace()](https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html)

Comment: Note: If the `$sdir = "<value>"`  string value does NOT end with a ``\`` backslash, then the way to select that would be `@{Name = "sDir"; Expression = { $_.FullName.Replace($sdir,"").TrimStart("\") }}` instead which uses [TrimStart()](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html) to remove the backslash from the output value if that's of importance.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I was able to cobble together what I want: https://superuser.com/a/1632687/62342   It's not perfect, but I think it will do. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, you are wecome!!!

Answer (score 3):

powershell will give you the best results. Run this and open the results in excel. Edit the paths as needed.

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -path c:\files\*.txt | export-csv c:\files\here.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I'm getting an error from `Get-ChildObject`. Could it be `Get-ChildItem` instead?

Comment: It should be [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

i am new in batch maybe this can help you
**for current directory**

```
for %F in (*.txt) do @echo %~zF  %F
```

**for subdirectories**

```
for /f %F in ('dir /s /r /b *.txt') do @echo %~zF  %F
```

**Output**

```
163197  O:\170801072959IMG-20170622-WA0006.txt
729213  O:\170805042647DSC033881.txt
679900  O:\170805045024crop.txt
723650  O:\170805071247temp.txt
66632  O:\170817035334DSC03625_comp.txt
89448  O:\170817035545DSC03569_comp.txt
84730  O:\pics\151104051533IMG_20151103_111229.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I added a `%~tF` to get the date and that works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the direction from a few people here, I was able to cobble everything together into (almost) exactly what I wanted:

```
# check for arguments
if (!$args) { echo "Please specify [path\]filespec. i.e., c:\temp\*.txt or *.txt"; return }
# get the path only
$path = Split-Path $Args  | Where-Object {$_ -ne ''}| Convert-Path
# if no path was specified, use the current directory
$path = IF ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($path)){ $pwd.path } else { $path }
# get the filespec (*.txt)
$filespec = Split-Path $Args -Leaf
write-output "`nShowing all $filespec contained under $path"
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filespec -File -Recurse |
Format-Table -Wrap @{ Name="Date"; Expression = { $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy  hh:mm:ss  ") }},
    @{ Name="Size"; Expression = { "{0,15:N0}" -f $_.Length }; Alignment="right"; },
    @{ Name="File"; Expression = { ($_.FullName -ireplace [regex]::Escape($path), "").TrimStart("\") }}
```

There are no totals at the end, but that's fine.

```
PS C:\> C:\utils\sdir.ps1 \users\default\documents\*.txt

Showing all *.txt contained under C:\users\default\documents

Date                              Size File
----                             ----- ----
11/14/2013  01:34:29               970 in\text\people.txt
08/27/2013  11:43:48               498 in\text\review.txt
08/14/2020  05:55:20               176 store\Documentation\Temporary0.txt
08/14/2020  05:55:20                52 store\Documentation\Temporary1.txt
08/14/2020  05:55:21               559 store\Documentation\Logs\Debug log.txt
01/20/2015  04:09:15             5,610 Letters\Letter.txt
12/30/2008  01:43:40             2,212 Misc\Poster.txt
07/30/2011  11:46:58               918 Misc\comments.txt
08/14/2010  04:13:04               523 Misc\Daily.txt
08/31/2010  08:51:24             2,840 Misc\review\overview.txt
01/05/2009  08:04:52             1,768 Misc\review\other.txt
```

The only issue is if you specify a directory without a filespec (e.g., `c:\temp` as opposed to `c:\temp\*.*`) and I would also like more spacing between the columns.